# Why don't people know Iron Man is Tony in the Extremis comic?

Tags: marvel, avengers, iron-man

According to a bunch of reading guides, Iron Man Extremis occurs during the early days of New Avengers right around House of M. So why is it that in Extremis, no one knows that Iron Man is Tony Stark? It doesn't make sense considering what happened during Avengers Disassembled.

Comment: I seem to recall an interview with Warren Ellis wherein he claimed he intentionally ignored a bunch of continuity.  Maybe someone can find it?  It's worth noting this is the first story in which Tony's origin is tied to Afghanistan rather than the Korean War, and the story opens with protestors complaining about Stark selling weapons, which he'd stopped decades ago in earlier continuity.  Overall:  soft reboot?  See also http://www.popmatters.com/review/invincible-iron-man-extremis-1-5/